# c++ memory allocation and rewriting the vector class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'm doing an assignment in c++ where we have to rewrite the std::vector class that inherits from an abstract Container class. We have to write methods for 'Vector' such as begin(), end(), push_back(), etc... 
Many of the basic std::vector Member functions found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

---

My question is multi-faceted mainly because I am a beginner and the memory of computers is fascinating. Also, sorry if this question is super specific or has similar answers on here but I'm really stuck because this is the first time I've dealt with memory.

---

Here are my Container and Vector class implementations:

```
template <typename T> 
class Container {
    protected:
        T* elem;
        int cap;
    public:
        virtual T& operator[](int i) = 0;
        virtual int size() = 0;
        ~ Container() { delete[] elem; }
};

template <typename T>
class Vector: public Container<T> {
    protected:
        using Container<T>::elem;
        using Container<T>::cap;
    private:
        int sz;
    public:
        // constructors
        Vector(); // default constructor
        Vector(int n); // fill constructor #1
        Vector(int n, T fill_val); // fill constructor #2
/*      // ~ Vector(); // destructors
unsure if the above is correct, because of the Container destructor                                
*/  
        // overloaded operators
        T& operator[](int i); // subscript overloading '[]'
        T& operator=(const Vector<T>& V); // assignment overloading '='
        // access methods
        T& front(); //returns a reference to the first element
        T& back(); //returns a reference to the last element
        // iterator methods
        T* begin(); // returns memory address of the first element
        T* end(); // returns memory address at the end
        // size methods
        int size() { return sz; }
        int capacity() { return cap; }
};
```

---

Part 2.

When/why do I need the destructor? I've tried to read up on destructors on Stack, but I feel more confused than clarified. I'm assuming the SegFault is coming from memory needing to be deallocated, and I know I'm supposed to be learning how to dynamically allocate memory with this assignment. The constructors and destructors are crucial for this process but can someone break it down as simply as possible for me?

---

EDIT:

I've fixed the segmentation fault by implementing Fureeish's answer. My code has been updated above.

The only remaining inquiry is to the destructor and its purpose. Do I need to implement one for `Vector` or will it be called automatically by `Container`?

Comment: Try writing a non-template version, for say a vector of `int`, without using inheritance.

Comment: As an aside, I find it a bit strange that `Container` `delete`s its pointer array without allocating or otherwise using it. The pointer array should be removed from the base class. I would imagine the definition of `Container` is given as per the assignment and can't be changed though.

Comment: Yeah we are supposed to implement the destructor in `Container`, but I'm also unsure when/how it deletes the array of pointers in `Vector`

Comment: Well, I'm sure you'll learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decided to manage the memory by yourself, but you never allocated any. You're missing some `new`s here and there. For example, given a:

```
Vector(int n, T fill_val) {
    sz = n;
    cap = 2*n;
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        elem[i] = fill_val; 
    }
}
```

the `for()` loop iterates over `elem`, which is an uninitialized pointer. You treat it like a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, but it simply points to some garbage value. Remember - first allocate, then work on (**only** when you decide to manage the memory yourself. Typically you should prefer using standard implementations).

The correct version should look like this:

```
Vector(int n, T fill_val) {
    sz = n;
    cap = 2*n;
    elem = new T[cap]; // or cap-1, depending on what you do with `end()`.
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        elem[i] = fill_val; 
    }
}
```

The fact that you never encountered this problem while using other constructors is just you being extremely lucky and *undefined behavior* being sneaky

Comment: Personally, I'd call it bad luck. I'd rather know where my UB is hiding any day of the week

Comment: @alterigel fair point. By *lucky* I meant that the code seemed to work, but obviously, from the developer's perspective, that's a really unfortunate event

Comment: Yes! Your line of code in two spots fixed it! (You're right, I was _lucky_, I needed it in another constructor) One last thing, `elem = new T[cap]` initializes an array of pointers of type T, and then I can iterate over them to set them to fill_val? Man, this assignment really makes me appreciate using std::vectors lol.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you're seeing the light at last.  And you can do anything you like with those elements, as I'm sure your tutor will be pleased to tell you.  If there is one.  Oh, why did you delete your comment?

Comment: @pickypoo1987 `elem = new T[cap]` does not initialize an array of pointers of type `T`. It dynamically allocated `cap` amount of `T`s. They are just objects, not pointers to them

Comment: @PaulSanders I deleted it because it made little sense when I re-read it, I apologize. It's true I _have_ enjoyed this assignment because I'm applying a lot of powerful new concepts, and it allows me to understand std::vectors at a simplified "under-the-hood" level. I'm just trying to seek guidance on OOD and memory! :)

Comment: Yes, you need guidance.